# Making column values bold based on other columns in python

Tags: python, format, conditional-statements, styles, bold

I am trying to figure out how to make column values in my pandas dataframe based on the values in another column, specifically concerning regression outputs and making coefficients that correspond to a low p-value bold. I am using python.

I have the following dataframe containing regression output results:

```
Model_run    Param_1    Param_2    Param_3   Param_1_pv   Param_2_pv   Param_3_pv 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1               .453       .756       .945          .06          .04          .03 
2               .452       .336       .342          .04          .03          .22 
3               .264      .443        .044          .33          .05          .32 
4               .356       .543       .033          .01          .05          .14 
5               .234      .435        .032          .04          .03          .09 
...
```

where the "Param" columns refer to coefficients for each parameter (independent variable) and pv means "P-value" for each parameter independent variable. And so I want to make the coefficient values corresponding to a p-value of <= 0.05 bold. I would show the output I want, but I don't think the code formatting here lets you use boldening.

How can I accomplish this in python? I have seen that I can use .style.applymap(), but I am confused about how to format the coefficients based on their corresponding p-value columns, since most tutorials just show how to format the columns themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.style.apply` with a custom function.

```
def bold(v, props="", threshold=0.05):
    if v.name + "_pv" not in df:
        return np.full(v.shape, "")
    return np.where(df[v.name + "_pv"].le(threshold), props, "") 

df.style.apply(bold, props="font-weight: bold", axis=0, threshold=0.05)
```

Workaround:

```
def bold(v, threshold=0.05):
    if v.name + "_pv" not in df:
        return np.full(v.shape, "")
    return np.where(df[v.name + "_pv"].le(threshold), "font-weight: bold", "") 

df.style.apply(bold, axis=0, threshold=0.05)
```

Output:

[image]

Insight:

The function seeks for a column suffixed with `_pv` and then do the comparison of that column against `threshold`.

If no column with `_pv` found, it will return an empty-string array to say that specific cell does not require styling (in this case, `font-weight: bold`).

If column with `_pv` found, it will apply `numpy.where` to make an array mixed with `props` and `""` to filter out cells for which styling needs to be applied.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do, but unfortunately it is not working for me with my actual research data. I tried your code, but just got the error message: “TypeError: (“bold() got an unexpected keyword argument ‘props’”, ‘occurred at index Color’)” where “Color” is referring to one of my additional columns in my dataframe, which is confusing me. Do you know how I might fix this?

Comment: I am also a bit confused how the function knows how to match up the parameter with its corresponding p-value, e.g. parameter 1 coefficient corresponding the p-value for parameter 1, and the coefficient for parameter 2 corresponding to the p-value for parameter 2 etc.?

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? You can remove `props` part and use it inside the function. `bold` uses series's name to find it's matcher: when received `Param_1`, it seeks for `Param_1_pv` by adding `_pv` and checking if that name exists in the data. Check the workaround and let me know.

Comment: Your work around suggestion worked perfectly, thank you. Though I noticed that I am unable to change the names of the "Param_X" columns, which I would like to do while keeping the boldening. Is that possible? I am guessing now, since that would change the name referencing the conditional statement relies on.